# How to scrape XML with R with conditions

Tags: r, xml, xpath, pmml

I require a some assistance please to help me scrape an attribute from an XML doc, when a condition is met. My apologies but I cannot provide a reproducible example but I am hopeful that the code that I can provide should suffice.

I require to scrape the name "Status_TOTS" from the 'name' attribute from the 'Datafield' tag **when** the 'value' attribute in the nested 'Extension' tag equals "set".

In general, I am scraping various elements from a PMML model (in XML). I have had progress so far by establishing nsDefs and ns objects and scraping with code similar to...

```
test_scrape = xpathSApply(pmml_model, "//x:DataField", xmlGetAttr, "name" , namespaces=ns)
```

where 'pmml_model' is passed as the doc. I just need to add the conditional element and have tried numerous ways with no success.

```
library(XML)
library(methods)    

nsDefs <- xmlNamespaceDefinitions(pmml_model)
ns <- structure(sapply(nsDefs, function(x) x$uri), names = names(nsDefs))
names(ns)[1] <- "x"

<DataField dataType="string" name="Status_TOTS" optype="categorical">
  <Extension extender="spss" name="storageType" value="string"/>
  <Extension extender="spss" name="measure" value="set"/>
  <Value property="valid" value="0000"/>
  <Value property="valid" value="0001"/>
  <Value property="valid" value="0010"/>
</DataField>
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `test_scrape = xpathSApply(pmml_model, "//x:DataField[x:Extension/@value='set']", ....)` ?

Comment: Thnx @har07, that did the trick! I must have tried 100 variations but just not that. Much appreciated.